# Parallelized multidimensional numerical integration in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am working on a problem that needs a numerical integration of a bivariate function, where each evaluation of the function takes about 1 minute. Since numerical integration on a single core would evaluate the function thousands to tens of thousand times, I would like to parallelize the calculation. Right now I am using the bruteforce approach that calculates a naive grid of points and add them up with appropriate area multipliers. This is definitely not efficient and I suspect any modern multidimensional numerical integration algorithm would be able to achieve the same precision with a lot fewer function evaluations. There are many packages in R that would calculate 2-d integration much more efficiently and accurately (e.g. R2Cuba), but I haven't found anything that can be easily parallelized on a cluster with SGE managed job queues. Since this is only a small part of a bigger research problem, I would like to see if this can be done with reasonable effort , before I try to parallelize one of the cubature-rule based methods in R by myself.

Comment: Why not run a loop over slices of your outermost integrand, assigning each slice to a different core?  `mcapply` comes to mind.

Comment: The question would then become how I can parallelize the outer integration, without looping over slices. There is a reason that adaptive quadrature and other things are used for one-dimensional integration. I would also like to limit each job under 6 hours so that I can queue them as normal jobs on SGE. Calculating the inner integral on one core would take a long time too.

Comment: You can't parallelize **any** function unless you can split it up into portions which are completely independent of each other. What you're willing or not willing to give up to get that independence is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that using [sparse grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_grid) achieves the best compromise between speed and accuracy in multi-dimensional integration, and it's easily parallized on the cluster because it doesn't involve any sequential steps. It won't be as accurate as other sequentially adpative integration algorithms but it is much better than the naive method because it provides a much sparser grid of points to calculate on each core.

The following R code deals with 2-dimensional integration, but can be easily modified for higher dimensions. The apply function towards the end can be easily parallelized on a cluster.

```
sg.int<-function(g,...,lower,upper)

{ require("SparseGrid")

 lower<-floor(lower)

 upper<-ceiling(upper)

 if (any(lower>upper)) stop("lower must be smaller than upper")

 gridss<-as.matrix(expand.grid(seq(lower[1],upper[1]-1,by=1),seq(lower[2],upper[2]-1,by=1)))

 sp.grid <- createIntegrationGrid( 'KPU', dimension=2, k=5 )

 nodes<-gridss[1,]+sp.grid$nodes

 weights<-sp.grid$weights

 for (i in 2:nrow(gridss))

 {
    nodes<-rbind(nodes,gridss[i,]+sp.grid$nodes)  

    weights<-c(weights,sp.grid$weights)

  }

  gx.sp <- apply(nodes, 1, g,...)
  val.sp <- gx.sp %*%weights
  val.sp
}
```